# SAP data changes not refreshing in Webpages - HYBRIS

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am updating the data through Hybris with the help of Impex files.
Data is not showing When i modify the data in SAP (Example: Global description changes not showing in the web pages).

Note: I am using direct input method LSMW for updating global description (MAKTX)

Any Suggestion please.....

Comment: What data are you changing using impel files ? Are you targeting the right catalog ?

Comment: Are the changes showing when you update data via impex? Or you mean with the help of LSMW you create impex files which are later being executed in hybris?
Are you able to check whether the data is really updated in db? If you see the changes in db, try to clear cache (hAC -> Monitoring -> Cache -> Clear).